# TFS On-premise Licensing Cost calculation

Tags: tfs, licensing

Does a local TFS license cost the same as a VSTS on Azure? What will be the best licensing option to have TFS on-premise?

Comment: This is not a programming question . Did you read this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 5):

**No**, there are not the same.

> To license TFS on-premise server, you’ll need a **TFS server license** and a
>   Windows operating system license (Windows Server is best) for each
>   machine running TFS, plus **a client access license for each person
>   connecting to TFS**. Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for
>   people who just access work items – assign them “Stakeholder” access,
>   which is free.
>
> Extensions to TFS such as Test Manager, Package Management, and
>   Private Pipelines require an additional purchase. Some TFS Extensions
>   are included with Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions and many
>   others are free. Paid extensions can also be purchased monthly, no
>   Visual Studio subscription is required.
>
> *TFS server costs $499 and includes 5 TFS CALs.  Additional TFS CALs are $499 each.*

Unlike the Classic Purchasing above, suggest you to use **Modern Purchasing**. The most advantage: No need to make a 3-year purchasing commitment for TFS—**you can pay month-to-month and cancel any time.**   For example:

- **Buy VSTS for TFS CALs.** When you buy VSTS users (starting at **$6/month**), those same users have a TFS CAL and can connect to any TFS in your organization. If those users also need TFS extensions
  like Test Manager or Package Management, or if you need additional
  Private Pipelines for your team, you can purchase these through the
  Visual Studio Marketplace. All VSTS charges are month-to-month. [See
  detailed instructions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/billing/buy-access-tfs-test-hub?view=tfs-2018)

For more info you could take a look at this official doc: **[Team Foundation Server Pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.sg%2F)**

---

Besides, If you want to double confirm this and  know more information about TFS license, you could call 1-800-426-9400, Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist, and you can get more detail information from there. Worldwide customers can use the Guide to Worldwide Microsoft Licensing Sites to find contact information in their locations: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/